# Node.Js authentication using Stormpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, stormpath, stormpath-express

```
 var auth = {
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password'
};

application.authenticateAccount(auth, function(err, result) {

  result.getAccount(function(err, account) {
    console.log('Account:', account);
  });
};
```

> I am getting an error **TypeError : Cannot read property 'getAccount' of undefined**

Comment: It's not working because the error is not `null`, eg: you have an error! The credentials are likely incorrect =)

Comment: Credentials are correct!

Comment: I don't think so! EG: throw a `console.log(err)` above your `result.getAccount` line, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You are right. But the credentials are correct. ** userMessage : ' Invalid username or password and developerMessage : Login attempt failed because there is no Account in the Application’s associated Account Stores with the specified username or email **

Comment: That means those credentials supplied are incorrect. Either that -- or the Directory which holds your user Account is NOT mapped to your Application.

Comment: I'm using the same href for creating and authenticating account. I don't  understand where the directory mismatch occurrs

Answer (score 1):

In the `authenticateAccount` callback, is there an error?  What does `console.log(err)` look like?

Comment: Error: 7104

Login attempt failed because there is no Account in the Application’s associated Account Stores with the specified username or email. There is an account with the specified email and password. I am using the same application for creating account as well as for authentication. But account is being created but not authenticating.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Can to tell us what types of account stores that you have mapped to your application, and which of the stores is being used to create new accounts (the default account store)?  Thanks!

Comment: I have created my own application, and the description  says Auto-created directory for the 'Movie Express' application . I don't know if I have answered the question!

Comment: That does, thanks!  Everything sounds like it's configured correctly.  Could you show us the rest of your Express application context?  If you get in touch with us via support@stormpath.com we can share code privately on there.  Thanks!